# Convert bar into points in hist() function

Tags: r, histogram

`hist()` will generate a histogram composed of lots of "bars"

How can I replace each bar with one point, so that many points together will look like a continuous curve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

some dummy data

```
x <- rnorm(50)

# create a histogram
.hist <- hist(x)

# look at the structure to see what is created when calling hist
str(.hist)

## List of 7
## $ breaks     : num [1:10] -2.5 -2 -1.5 -1 -0.5 0 0.5 1 1.5 2
## $ counts     : int [1:9] 1 2 5 6 8 10 10 5 3
## $ intensities: num [1:9] 0.04 0.08 0.2 0.24 0.32 0.4 0.4 0.2 0.12
## $ density    : num [1:9] 0.04 0.08 0.2 0.24 0.32 0.4 0.4 0.2 0.12
## $ mids       : num [1:9] -2.25 -1.75 -1.25 -0.75 -0.25 0.25 0.75 1.25 1.75
## $ xname      : chr "x"
## $ equidist   : logi TRUE
## - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"

# we could plot the mids (midpoints) against the counts
with(.hist, plot(mids, counts))
```

[image]

Or you could simply use `density`

```
plot(density(x))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. But I'm really newby for R. I put your script into terminal, but it doesn't work. I even don't quite understand str() function, what does "##" refer to ?

Comment: `str` gives you the structure of the object. I included this to show you how to find the bits of the object created when calling `hist` given that you wanted to use the information in another way. `#` indicates a comment (something that `R` will not evaluate). The `##` is just commenting out the output to make it easier for you to copy and paste into an `R` session.  What does not work? What error do you get? Where does it stop working?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the density plot for a histogram. Here are two previous answers:  The first shows how to overlay the density plot on the histogram.  And the second on how to create the density plot along.

[Axis-labeling in R histogram and density plots; multiple overlays of density plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246040/axis-labeling-in-r-histogram-and-density-plots-multiple-overlays-of-density-plo)

[How to Plot Density from Frequency Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412300/how-to-plot-density-from-frequency-table)